# SQL - Add up column value singletable

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I have a table Like This

```
Id|purchase_date | Purchase_price
1 |02-May-17     |$10.00
2 |02-May-17     |$20.00
3 |02-May-17     |$30.00
```

I want to write a query where the  sum of all purchase_price will calculated on the basis of purchase_date.
Can Someone Please suggest the query?

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using; don't store '$', and store dates using a date data type.

Comment: Can you show your expected result to ensure that the answer best fits what your after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this with groupby clause

```
select sum(replace(Purchase_price, '$', '')) as total from tbl group by purchase_date
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Sunny, 
I had already tried this one ,But its not Working.
Thanks For the Replay.

Comment: Hello Sunny,I have tried the edited query ,but every time the output is 61135.88000000002.the ans which is coming is not depend on purchase_price values

Comment: hii @AskitRaina check screenshot i tried it and it's working fine.

Comment: It Worked..Thanks a lot Man!

Comment: @AskitRaina but you accept another answer it's strange.

Comment: Sorry,It was clicked by Mistake.

Comment: No problem bro! (y)

Comment: Hey Sunny, How can i directly display this value which we get using this query.Because the output was which came was  in 'total' column but i don't have any total column in database

Comment: Hii Askit total is an alias of column u can directly  get total as column name in your code.

Comment: Done..Thanks!(y)

Answer (score 0):

Use Mysql `Replace` function to remove `$` from price then user `SUM` followed by `group by` function like

```
SELECT SUM(REPLACE(Purchase_price,'$','')) AS price from tablename group by purchase_date
```

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php

Answer (score 0):

Let just say that you go dynamic currency symbol

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(SUBSTR(Purchase_price, 2) as DECIMAL(4,2))) FROM tablename GROUP BY purchase_date;
```